# display message error jsf

Tags: jsf

i need to manage some error messages in my managed bean by using FacesMessage.
I am using the `<h:message>` tag and not `<h:messages>` but for some reasons , the error messages are displayed in the bottom in my page and not in the `<h:message>` tag

jsf page

```
<h:form id="myForm">
        <table width="100%" height="600" border="0">

            <tr >
                <td width="150">Id *</td>
                <td width="250"><h:inputText id="idInterne" value="#{resource.ID_interne}" required="true" requiredMessage="Id interne missing! " /></td>
                <td ><h:message for="idInterne" style="color:red" id="idInterneError" /></td>
            </tr>
```

My managed bean part ( where i deals with the facemessage)

```
catch (SQLException e) {
              String message = e.getMessage();  
            if (message.indexOf("ck1") != -1) {
                FacesMessage idInterneExists = new FacesMessage( "Id interne already exists in database !" );
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage( "myForm:idInterne", idInterneExists );
            }
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved
For some reasons , the form id was not `"myForm:id:interne"` but `"j_idt5:myForm:id:interne"`